# Do decimal division without changig x87 registers

Tags: c, x86, division, cpu-registers

I’m in a strange situation I have coded myself into, trapped! I am taking an OS course where we are writing a non-preemptive scheduler, i am in a situation where I need to make some easy calculation about time measurement in a context switch.

For my average calculation I am in need for division with decimals, my code now calls a C function from assembler for the calculation and prints the result to screen, this C function uses **double**, later i realized that **double** division will cause changes to the x87 registers because the **get_time**(C function) function is called right before the context switching and right after. Is there a way to do decimal division avoiding changes to x87 registers? I sorely need some tips and help.

Comment: You could do fixed-point division with integers as long as you can scale the inputs to the desired precision without causing an overflow.

Comment: If you aren't saving/restoring the x87 registers around the context switch, then the threads shouldn't be using them, so it should be OK for the OS to trash them.

Comment: Context switch saves and restores x87 registers and is used by 4 threads to calculate Monte Carlo Pi. Bochs gives math_abort: MSDOS compatibility FPU exception!

Comment: Does [this](http://f.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=11954) help?

Comment: Not really sure, because when removing the devision or using int instead of double, no exception is raised. For me there is logical that division before context switching will change the state in x87 registers, or am I wrong?

Comment: If you save the x87 regs, then do the division, then restore the oth er thread's x87 regs, it should be fine. Is the exception occuring in the context switch code, or in the thread after the context switch completes?

Comment: can you just use another timing function that returns `int`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much skills in asm and registers uses, but maybe :

- what if you push your register and pop it at the end ?
- You said that double division change to the x87 registers, what about `float` ?

Comment: I actually use GNU Assembler, float also changes x87 register :(

Comment: This is not really an answer - but a suggestion - consider using a comment